# How do I access git once I have downloaded it on my Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, git

I downloaded Git 2.3.5 Mavericks via http://git-scm.com/downloads. After installation I could not open or find git. So I followed the Read Me instructions that came with git. So I removed stubs:

sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-system

Then installed Tcl/Tk Aqua. To check if git works I typed this command in my terminal:

$ git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"

The response was:

Illegal instruction

Please help.

Comment: Why do you rename `git` to `git-system`? Best way to install `git` and other linux tools on Mac is use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), install homebrew then `brew install git`

Comment: ^ what @number5 said. Also understand that git is a command line tool. You will not be opening git like a typical desktop app. There is not an icon for it in your apps folder. To initialize a git repo, go to that directory and type ``git init``

Comment: in terminal, when you enter `which git`, what do you get as a response?

Comment: @mchen.ja and what should be the correct value ? I get /usr/local/bin/git
But in my case, this command is okay using it directly in the terminal, but eclipse still runs in the Apple Stub.

Comment: @GaëlOberson that sounds right for git. But Eclipse and git are different pieces of software, so you'll probably have to ask your question about Eclipse in a separate post.